# FATAL: Remote call on jenkins node server failed

Tags: jenkins, server, nodes, hudson, jenkins-job-dsl

We are using jenkins version is 2.121.3.
For java JDK versions we are using different versions for master and slave machines.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This issue will occurs only for security jobs. Which they are added through jenkins node.
This issue will occurs only in occasionally.
Some times job getting succeed sometimes getting failed.

For temporary solution we are relaunching the nodes.
At that time it was working.
We are searching for permanent solution but we unable to find it.

Comment: You should really take real screenshots instead of using camera. The text in your pictures is awful.

Comment: Sorry @JamesZ due to security reasons I can't able to real screenshots. Kindly do the needful the above issue.

Comment: If that's a company policy, I'm quite sure you're then not allowed to take pictures of your screen with a camera either. Otherwise that policy makes no sense...